# Connecting hosted MongoDB with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mongodb

How can I connect the shared MongoDB database to GeoServer?

I'm trying to follow https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/mongodb/index.html
but not sure how the url will be , I have attached screenshot of the URL and other params that I'm trying

[image]

getting this error when I tries URI - mongodb://krishnaglodha:pwd@cluster0.9se3q.mongodb.net/ports

[image]